# Tapestry 3: cannot get messages from properties file

Tags: templates, properties, tapestry

I have tapestry 3 template in HelloWorld.html and HelloWorld.properties file with strings in the same folder, but cannot get them.

I've tried :

The only output that i have is [PAGETITLE].

Here is the content of properties file:

pageTitle=Hello world

Answer (score 0):

The .properties file needs to go in the same folder as the corresponding class: probably under src/main/resources (it of course varies with the layout of your project).