# Tapestry messages - Inject fails with Nullpointer

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a Tapestry application (filter name is "app") with app.properties residing under WEB-INF. I want to use the properties in a simple Java class where I'd like to inject them via

```
@Inject
Messages messages;
```

However, this keeps on failing and gives me a nullpointer exception. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745368/tapestry-3-cannot-get-messages-from-properties-file) on stackoverflow, but that solution does not apply to the problem here. Placing a properties-File in WEB-INF should be perfectly well ([as outlined here](http://tapestry.apache.org/localization.html)). However, is there any specific configuration or anything I have to keep in mind with respect to packages, i.e. does the @Inject only work in specific packages in the application? Or does the java class need to have some specifics (default constructor, ...)?

Comment: I'm having a similiar problem (with injecting a service though), have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Well, I think the Idea of Bob Harner was correct and placing it in the correct folder fixed it...

Comment: This didn't work for me tho - I had to directly call functions of the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Use **@InjectService** Annotation instead of **@Inject**

```
@InjectService("EmailService")
private EmailService emailService;
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can only @Inject into classes that Tapestry manages (pages, components, mixins, Tapestry IOC services). Can you turn your "simple Java class" into a Tapestry IOC service class?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Bob. I have added the class as    binder.bind(EmailService.class, EmailServiceImpl.class); in Tapestry's AppModule class (in the bind-Method). However I am still running into the same issue.

Comment: Is the class in the "services" package? If not, move it there and see if that works.

Comment: @BobHarner I did this, but it still didn't work. I know it's nearly two years later, but do you have any ideas?